# How to uniquely identify phase difference between harmonics?

Tags: phase

Let's say I have a multi-frequencies signal of 440Hz and 880Hz, slightly out of phase.

I can take a chunk of the signal and calculate phase difference of the two frequencies with FFT bins. However, since frequencies are different, the phase difference will differ depending upon where I took the chunks, despite they are taken ***from the same signal***.

I wonder whether there is a way to **uniquely identify phase difference between harmonics**, with arbitrary chunks? (so that I can identify harmonic signals.)

Comment: Phase relative to what?  1970 Midnight GMT? Some start time when you flipped a switch, or other event?  Some fundamental periodicity or pitch interval zero crossing?  Or ?

Comment: My question is how to come up with a definition of  "phase difference" representing uniquely the same signal from which arbitrary chunks are taken. I think @robert bristow-johnson has given a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

i am assuming this is a periodic (or quasi-periodic) function.  also seems like the signal is a musical tone.  periodic signals have a period, $P$, and the reciprocal of that period is the fundamental frequency; $f_0 \triangleq \frac{1}{P}$

or, as angular frequency; $\omega_0 = 2 \pi f_0 = \frac{2 \pi}{P}$ .

the periodic signal is $x(t)$ where

$$ x(t+P) = x(t)  \qquad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} $$

it can be represented as a Fourier series

$$ \begin{align}
x(t) \ &= \ a_0 \ + \ 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \cos(k \omega_0 t) - b_k \sin(k \omega_0 t) \\
 &= \ a_0 \ + \ 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \frac{e^{j k \omega_0 t} + e^{-j k \omega_0 t}}{2} \ - \ b_k \frac{e^{j k \omega_0 t} - e^{-j k \omega_0 t}}{2j} \\
 &= \ a_0 \ + \ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (a_k + jb_k) e^{j k \omega_0 t} \ + \ (a_k - jb_k) e^{-j k \omega_0 t} \\
 &= \ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k \ e^{j k \omega_0 t} \\
\end{align} $$

where

$$ c_k =
\begin{cases}
a_{-k} - jb_{-k}, & \quad \text{for } k < 0 \\
a_0, & \quad\quad k = 0 \\
a_k + jb_k, & \quad\quad k > 0 
\end{cases} $$

and, going in the other direction,

$$ \begin{array}{lcl}
a_0 & = & c_0 \\
a_k & = & \Re\{c_k \} \quad\quad \text{for } k>0\\
b_k & = & \Im\{c_k \} \quad\quad\quad k>0
\end{array} $$

note that for real $a_k$ and real $b_k$, then

$$ c_{-k} = c_k^* = \text{"complex conjugate of } c_k \text{ "}$$

it's easier to get $c_k$ from $x(t)$ and then compute $a_k$ and $b_k$ from the $c_k$ which is:

$$ c_k = \tfrac{1}{P} \int\limits_{t_0}^{t_0+P} x(t) \, e^{-j k \omega_0 t} \, \mathrm{d}t \qquad \text{for any } t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$$

you can uniquely define the phase of overtones (or harmonics apart from the fundamental) with reference to the fundamental **if** there is any energy at the fundamental.  (it is not always the case that a periodic signal has non-zero energy in its own fundamental frequency.)

now it's also true that:

$$ \begin{align}
x(t) \ &= \ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k \ e^{j k \omega_0 t} \\
 &= \ a_0 \ + \ 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \cos(k \omega_0 t) - b_k \sin(k \omega_0 t) \\
 &= \ a_0 \ + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} r_k \cos(k \omega_0 t + \phi_k) \\
\end{align} $$

where

$$ \begin{align}
r_k &= 2 \big| a_k + j\,b_k \big|  \\
 &= 2 \sqrt{a_k^2 + b_k^2}  \\
\\
\phi_k &= \arg \{a_k + j\,b_k \}  \\
 &= \operatorname{atan2}(b_k, a_k)  \\
\end{align} $$

now, the phases of all of the harmonics are relative to some time $t=0$, but that reference time can be defined in such a way that the phase of the fundamental is zero.

let

$$\begin{align}
 \tilde{x}(t) \ &\triangleq \ x(t - \tfrac{\phi_1}{\omega_0}) \\
 &= \ a_0 \ +  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} r_k \cos \big(k \omega_0 (t - \tfrac{\phi_1}{\omega_0}) + \phi_k \big) \\
 &= \ a_0 \ +  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} r_k \cos(k \omega_0 t + \phi_k - k\phi_1) \\
 &= \ a_0 \ +  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} r_k \cos(k \omega_0 t + \tilde{\phi}_k) \\
\end{align} $$

where $ \tilde{\phi}_k \triangleq \phi_k - k\phi_1 $.

you can see that $\tilde{\phi}_1 = 0$, that we defined our origin of $t$ so that the phase of the fundamental (when $k=1$) is 0.  then all of the other harmonics have their phases referenced to that *"first harmonic"* or fundamental.  the only problem is that the amplitude of that fundamental must not be zero.  $r_1 \ne 0$ so that the reference phase, $\phi_1 = \arg \{a_1 + j\,b_1 \}$, can be determined.